How to process user input and convert it to int
total=0
while True:
    
    number= int(input('enter nam: \n'))
    
    if number=='done':
        break
    
    total=number+total
    
print(total)

      File "d:\python\lo.py", line 4, in <module>
    number= int(input('enter nam: \n'))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'done'
PS D:\python>  

the question is that you can get a number from the character but after the word "done" that program stops asking for user input and give you the total result.
my problem is that i get two errors every time when i put only input and when i put int(input) it doesn't add up at all

You're calling int() immediately, which does not give the user an opportunity to enter a non-number answer such as "done".

You need to wait to call int() until after you check if the answer is a word.

You need to add an else statement for adding the totals. You can assign 'number' as an int there.
else:
number=int(number)
total=number+total

In the future, please pick a meaningful title. All questions on this site are about fixing something and everybody asking is hoping for an answer.

Only use stackoverflow if you already searched and found nothing

You directly try to convert the user input into an integer value. You should check before the conversion if it is indeed a numeric input.
total = 0

while True:
    number = input('enter number: \n')

    if number.isnumeric():
        total += int(number)
    elif number == 'done':
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong input, try again.")

print(total)


Your issue is that you are attempting to parse a string as an int.
You can do something like this:
total=0
while True:
    
    number= input('enter nam: \n')
    
    if number=='done':
        break
    else:
        total=int(number)+total
    
print(total)

